How to sort two inner index ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>?
How to sort ArrayLists with two values, so that first value will have higher priority and second lower.
ArrayList<> myArrayList = new ArrayList<>;

for(i = 0; i <4; i++) {
    ArrayList<> pair = new ArrayList<>;
    pair.add(i);
    pair.add(i);
    myArrayList.add(pair);
}

//in similar style
pairs (1,2) (3,1) (0,1) (0,0)
myArrayList.add(pairs);

//so that
// myArrayList contains: ( (0,0),(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(1,2),(3,1),(0,1),(0,0) )

public void sortMethod() {
    //some code
}
    
sortMethod();

// myArrayList contains: ( (0,0),(0,0),(0,1) (1,1),(1,2), (2,2), (3,1),(3,3) )

